# How to convert char (e.g., "[1, 2, 3]" ) to a list (e.g., [1, 2, 3])

Tags: r, string, list

Is there a nice way to convert a column of chars in a dataframe to a list in R Studio?

e.g.

convert type chr

```
"[1, 2, 3]"
"[11, 24, 3]"
"[1, 21, 3]"
"[14, 2, 31]"
```

to list

```
[1, 2, 3]
[11, 24, 3]
[1, 21, 3]
[14, 2, 31]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are not lists in R; they look like lists in python (language) and json (structure). We can capitalize on the latter:

```r
vec <- c("[1, 2, 3]", "[11, 24, 3]", "[1, 21, 3]", "[14, 2, 31]")
jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(paste(vec, collapse = "\n")), 
                    simplifyDataFrame = FALSE, simplifyMatrix = FALSE)
#  Imported 4 records. Simplifying...
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# [[2]]
# [1] 11 24  3
# [[3]]
# [1]  1 21  3
# [[4]]
# [1] 14  2 31
```

Comment: really a magic with `textConnection`, superb! +1!

Comment: Frankly, I dislike the requirement for `textConnection`, I've always thought that `jsonlite` was too restrictive on that part.

Answer (score 2):

What about `gsub` + `str2lang` + `eval`?

```
> s <- c("[1, 2, 3]", "[11, 24, 3]", "[1, 21, 3]", "[14, 2, 31]")

> lapply(gsub("\\[(.*)\\]", "c(\\1)", s), function(x) eval(str2lang(x)))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 11 24  3

[[3]]
[1]  1 21  3

[[4]]
[1] 14  2 31
```

---

Another option is using `py_eval` from `reticulate` package

```
> library(reticulate)

> lapply(s, py_eval)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 11 24  3

[[3]]
[1]  1 21  3

[[4]]
[1] 14  2 31
```

Comment: I find it interesting that you're preferring `Map` with a single list/vector over `lapply`. Is there a particular reason? Perhaps unfortunately (due to what I think of as elegant-completeness of `Map`), benchmarking suggests that `lapply` is faster between the two, even if we remove `unname`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your adivce! Sorry that it's some of my bad coding habit :P. I updated my solutions.

Comment: It wasn't criticism, it was curiosity. Perhaps in an ideal world, `lapply` would be a special-case for `Map`, and `Map` would be the top-tier function. Unfortunately, `Map` is just a wrapper around `mapply`, and its generality appears to make it 5-10% slower (with this data/code). This is where some "interesting" inconsistencies in R reside: `sapply` (simplifying) calls `lapply` (always a list), yet the multi-arg equivalents are reversed: `Map` (always a list) calls `mapply` (simplifying). Oddness.

Comment: @r2evans yes, I definitely agree with your point of view. I get used to `Map` since it is handy, but it is indeed less efficient than `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a way using `strsplit`.

```
strsplit(x, '\\D+') |> lapply(`[`, -1)
# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "11" "24" "3" 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "1"  "21" "3" 
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "14" "2"  "31"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c("[1, 2, 3]", "[11, 24, 3]", "[1, 21, 3]", "[14, 2, 31]")
```